# Look dev not showing any objects

Tags: interface

i have recently started using blender 2.8 and there is this look dev preview mode i tried but it doesn't show any of my model instead only black patches are visible in the place of my objects. here is how it looks. How do i fix it? Also eevee doesn't render any stuff on my pc so i use cycles.. [image: Look dev preview]

[image: Model_solid]

Comment: Sounds like you may have trouble with your graphics driver, try to update it.

Comment: But cycles is doing well.. Does eevee need graphic card only and doesn't use pc for its proper function?

Comment: Yes, Eevee renders only on the GPU (https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/EEVEE#Limitations). Rendering issues are typically happening because of problems with the  graphics driver (https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)

Comment: Oh OK.. Thanks a lot.